# Picking the maximum value from an alpha-numeric column in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, memo

I've a table that has a column with data type 'Memo'.
This field contains values like "X003", "X0022", "X002", "X0030", "X0031", "X004". In short the first "X00" part is common, and the rest part is a integer.
I want to select that row which contains the largest integer in the second part via a sql query. How should i write the sql?
If it was only a integer, I would use "MAX()" in sql to get the maximum value. But it's different from that. What should I do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT max(val(mid([col],3))) FROM thetable;
```

I.e. Select the maximum of the value after the 3rd character, cast to a number (or 0 if not convertible).

Comment: one more question: Will this return 0 if there is no records in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `MID()` in your query to get the last two characters and then convert them to integer or even do a `MAX()` directly on the chunk.

Comment: My bad. It doesn't. Looks like I'm working with just too many languages. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
How should i write the sql?
```

If you are looking for sql query

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CONVERT(INT,CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[a-z]%',REVERSE(memo)) > 0
      THEN RIGHT(memo,PatIndex('%[a-z]%',REVERSE(memo))-1)
      ELSE NULL END)) AS maxmemo
FROM Table1
```